# How to set OnClickListener to Grid items to start unique fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, onclicklistener, android-gridview

I've created a gridView with different items and want to start a unique fragment from each items. As in the below code it shows only one fragment on clicking each item. How can I make it start unique fragments on each item click?

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FavouriteFragment()).commit();

                FragmentManager manager1 = getFragmentManager();
                manager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Category1()).commit();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this and it worked.

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FavouriteFragment()).commit();


                         break;

                    case 1:
                        FragmentManager manager1 = getFragmentManager();
                        manager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Category1()).commit();

                        break;

                }



            }
        });
```